# Optimize tables used more than once: make dataframe persistent or save as parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I heard Spark SQL is lazy: whenver a result table is referred, Spark recalculates the table :(

For example,

```
WITH tab0 AS (
   -- some complicated SQL that generates a table 
   -- with size of Giga bytes or Tera bytes
), 

tab1 AS (
   -- use tab0
),

tab2 AS (
   -- use tab0
),

...

tabn AS (
   -- use tab0
),

select * from tab1 
join tab2 on ...
...
join tabn on ...
...
```

Spark could recalculate tab0 N times.

To avoid this, it is possible to save tab0 as a temp table. I found two solutions.

1) save tab0 into parquet, then load it into a temp view

https://community.hortonworks.com/articles/21303/write-read-parquet-file-in-spark.html
[How does createOrReplaceTempView work in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011846/how-does-createorreplacetempview-work-in-spark)

2) make tab0 persistent

https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/rdd-programming-guide.html#rdd-persistence

Which one is better in terms of query speed?

Answer (score 2):

If you have enough memory to hold the data, using `dataFrame.cache()` will be faster than writing to disk as Parquet and using a TempView to access it. The TempView will potentially go to disk N times.

If you don't have enough memory, I'd benchmark and see if there's a difference between persisting with the MEMORY_AND_DISK storage level and between writing to Parquet. It's hard for me to imagine that the disk format that Spark uses would be *less* efficient than Parquet (because why not just use Parquet in that case?), but I've learned to be careful with my assumptions when optimizing Spark code.