# How to correctly create a view in SparkSQL in Java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to do a very basic thing, but I get an error for which I can't find a solution.

What I want to do is to be able to execute SQL queries on a dataframe. To do this, I saw in the documentation [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/sql-getting-started.html#running-sql-queries-programmatically), you need to create a view from the dataframe. The problem is that although I do exactly what is written in the documentation, IntelliJ it keeps giving me a compile error.

This is my code:

```
    @Override
public Long execute() {
    log.info("Starting processing query");
    Instant start = Instant.now();


    Dataset<Row> dataframe = this.hdfsIO.readParquetAsDataframe(vaccineAdministrationSummaryFile);
//    Dataset<Row> dataframe = this.sparkSession.read().parquet(this.hdfsUrl + inputDir + "/" + filename);
    dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("query");

    Dataset<Row> sqlDF = sparkSession.sql("SELECT * FROM query");
```

The line `sparkSession.sql(SELECT * FROM query);` gives me an error and a warning:

- Warning: No data sources are configured to run this SQL and provide advanced code assistance. Disable this inspection via problem menu (alt+enter).
- Error: Unable to resolve table 'query' .

Why does this happen if my code is pretty much the same as the one in the documentation?

Running `sparkSession.catalog().listTables().show(false);` after `dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("query");` i get this:

```
21/05/31 09:36:29 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 27.591936 ms
21/05/31 09:36:29 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 11.52196 ms
21/05/31 09:36:29 INFO CodeGenerator: Code generated in 15.643281 ms
+-----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|name |database|description|tableType|isTemporary|
+-----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|query|null    |null       |TEMPORARY|true       |
+-----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

Istead, running the same command before `dataframe.createOrReplaceTempView("query");` i get this:

```
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
|name|database|description|tableType|isTemporary|
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
+----+--------+-----------+---------+-----------+
```

The function `readParquetAsDataframe()` is defined as follows, the string passed is the path of the file in the hdfs:

```
    public Dataset<Row> readParquetAsDataframe(String filename){
        return this.sparkSession.read().parquet(this.hdfsUrl + inputDir + "/" + filename);
}
```

I also imagined that a problem could lie in how I build the SparkSession because I don't specify any configuration, but if so I wouldn't even know how to configure it properly.
The SparkSession is build as follows:

```
SparkSession spark = SparkSession
    .builder()
    .appName("Project 1")
    .getOrCreate();
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How does createOrReplaceTempView work in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011846/how-does-createorreplacetempview-work-in-spark)

Comment: No, I had already read that answer, but it contains the information that is already available in the documentation, nothing more.

Comment: Do you _really_ need raw sql? Using the available dataframe selection methods are more optimized at compilation time

Comment: Honestly I think I can do without it, but I tried to write this instruction and since I got this error and I don't understand why I posted this question to understand what is happening..

Comment: What do you see if you put `spark.catalog.listTables.show(false)` right after `createOrReplaceTempView(...)`?

Comment: @mazaneicha i added what i get... it seems that the view has been created...

Comment: That seems to indicate that the problem is with `this.hdfsIO.readParquetAsDataframe(...)`. Can you now do a `dataframe.show(false)` before defining a view?

Comment: @mazaneicha I added more details. Why do you say the problem is in `this.hdfsIO.readParquetAsDataframe(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have java code. Check this JDBC example out and reading parquet is no different once you collect your `DataSet<Row>`, please pay attention to comments.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        
        SparkSession sparkSession = SparkSession.builder()
                                .master("local")
                                .appName("Test App")
                                .getOrCreate();

        // JDBC connection details
        String driver = "com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver";
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://192.168.1.113:3306/db";
        String user = "user";
        String pass = "password";
        
        // JDBC Connection and load table in Dataframe
        Dataset<Row> trans = sparkSession.read()
                                .format("jdbc")
                                .option("driver", driver)
                                .option("url", url)
                                //your table name here
                                .option("dbtable", "<table name>")
                                .option("user", user)
                                .option("password", pass).load();
        
        //your table view name here
        trans.createOrReplaceTempView("<table_view_name>");

        Dataset<Row> sqlResult = sparkSession
                                    //your same table view name here
                                    .sql("select firstname,lastname from <table_view_name>");

        sqlResult.foreach(f -> {
            //print the firstname from your table
            System.out.println("firstname -> "+f.get(0));
        });

    }
```