# What to use to store intermediate data in Spark?

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, view

What's the difference between storing intermediate tables in Dataframes or TempViews? Is there difference in memory?

Comment: over apps or within the app?

Comment: Within one app.

Comment: What is the true thrust of your question. The answer is not an answer imho. Intermediate tables for what? The df when evaluated is also intermediate.

Comment: Can you respond to the answers and select which one u think is best?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Dataframes` themselves are intermediate 'tables'. That can be cached to memory and/or disk. I leave aside the notion of code via Catalyst.

From the manuals on `tempviews`:

*Running SQL Queries Programmatically*

- The sql function on a SparkSession enables applications to run SQL queries programmatically and returns the result as a DataFrame.
- In order to do this you register the dataFrame as a SQL temporary view. This is a "lazy" artefact and there must already be a data frame / dataset present. It's just needs registering to allow the SQL interface.

  - `Caching` of the underlying dataframe(s) help(s) in terms of repeated access.
  - The tempview is a reference in memory to a dataframe, with no overhead generally.

> So in summary, within a Spark App, the dataframe is a temporary data
> store / intermediate table you could argue on the latter. If you need complex SQL against a
> dataframe that the dataframe API cannot handle, then we use the
> tempview. That is different to spark sql against a real Hive or jdbc read table, but the interface is the same.

This btw is a good reference:
https://medium.com/@kar9475/data-sharing-between-multiple-spark-jobs-in-databricks-308687c99897

Answer (score 0):

You can think of TempView as a temporary hive table that exists as long as the underlying Spark session is not closed.

So if you have a dataframe `df` and run `df.createOrReplaceTempView("something")`, you can retrieve the df by `val df = spark.table("something")` anywhere in the project (within same Spark Session) as long as the `createOrReplaceTempView` was called first.

Additional info here [How does createOrReplaceTempView work in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011846/how-does-createorreplacetempview-work-in-spark/44013035)