# Which method is more memory efficient createOrReplaceView or saveAsTable

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, hive, scala-spark

I've a dataframe from hive table I'm doing some changes to it, then while saving it again in hive as a new table which method should I use ? Assume this dataframe has 70 million record, I want to make saving process memory & time efficient.

**For eg.** 
Dataframe name = `df`

1. `df.createOrReplaceView(new_table)` 
   `SQL("create table new_table as select * from new_table)`
2. `df.write.saveAsTable("new_table")`

Answer (score 0):

The way I see it there's no way operation 1 can be more efficient.
`createOrReplaceView` is creating a temporary table in memory, you can read about it in [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011846/how-does-createorreplacetempview-work-in-spark).

As such between (1) Reading from disk to create a temp table in memory, to write the same table to disk, and (2) Reading from disk to write to disk, number 2 seems the obvious favorite.

If this answer doesn't satisfy you. You can always try both ways and check the total time and memorySeconds consumed in the YARN application UI.