# Avoid reading all records with AWS Glue dynamicframe

Tags: aws-glue

I have a postgresql database with millions records tables. I'm working with AWS Glue and I want to filter data at sql server level but when i execute `toDF()` the `dynamic_frame` fetch all the records.

```
DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
                        database = dataSourceCatalogDataBase, 
                        table_name = dataSourceCatalogTableName,
                        redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], 
                        transformation_ctx = "DataSource0"
                        )

DataSource0.toDF()
```

is any way to filter the data at sql server?

Thanks

I tried `additional_options`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way which you can convert a Glue DynamicFrame to a Spark dataframe with the result of a SQL query.

```py
DataSource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
                        database = dataSourceCatalogDataBase, 
                        table_name = dataSourceCatalogTableName,
                        redshift_tmp_dir = args["TempDir"], 
                        transformation_ctx = "DataSource0"
                        )

DataSource0.toDF().createOrReplaceTempView("TempViewName")

df = spark.sql("select * from TempViewName where <condition>")
```

Related SO: [How does createOrReplaceTempView work in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44011846/how-does-createorreplacetempview-work-in-spark)

Comment: Hi. what work for us is:

df1 = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://xxxxx/yyyyy").option("query", "SELECT * FROM table where pushed_at>'2023-01-03'").option("user", "xxx").option("password", "xxx").load()

Comment: This will read as a Spark dataframe directly (different from the topic). In addition, reading DataSource0 as a DynamicFrame enables Glue features such as [job bookmark](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/monitor-continuations.html).