# Spark AnalysisException global table or view not found

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I get the following error:

> 18/03/14 15:31:11 ERROR ApplicationMaster: User class threw exception:
>   org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Table or view not found:
>   products; line 1 pos 42

This is my code:

```
val spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("Test")
                .getOrCreate()

val products = spark.read.parquet(productsPath)
products.createGlobalTempView("products")

val q1 = spark.sql("SELECT PERCENTILE(product_price, 0.25) FROM products").map(_.getAs[Double](0)).collect.apply(0)
```

What am I doing wrong?
Is it possible to do the same thing in Spark without using `sql`?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `products.registerTempTable("products")`?

Comment: @ErnestKiwele: `registerTempTable` is deprecated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**TEMPORARY VIEW**

Just use `createOrReplaceTempView` as

```
products.createOrReplaceTempView("products")

val q1 = spark.sql("SELECT PERCENTILE(product_price, 0.25) FROM products").map(_.getAs[Double](0)).collect.apply(0)
```

**GLOBAL TEMPORARY VIEW**

If you use [global temp view](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#global-temporary-view) then you should do

```
products.createGlobalTempView("products")

val q1 = spark.sql("SELECT PERCENTILE(product_price, 0.25) FROM global_temp.products").map(_.getAs[Double](0)).collect.apply(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

All the global temporary views are created in Spark preserved temporary `global_temp` database.

Below should work-

```scala
val q1 = spark.sql("""SELECT PERCENTILE(product_price, 0.25) 
    FROM global_temp.products""").map(_.getAs[Double](0)).collect.apply(0)
```

Spark has 2 different types of views, `Tempview` and `globalTempView`, see post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774187/spark-createorreplacetempview-vs-createglobaltempview) for more details.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use sql API you can try

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.Window

val wdw =  Window.partitionBy($"Field1", $"Field2").orderBy($"Field".asc)

products.withColumn("percentile",functions.ntile(100).over(wdw))
```