# Purpose of Spark catalog/temp views

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

My understanding of Spark is that, in general, you would use something like Pyspark to load up for example a CSV file into dataframe(s) and then do various transformations and aggregations on them. If the result is a small aggregation you might pull the results back to Python, whereas if it's larger you might push the resulting dataframes to a warehouse as permanent SQL tables.

I know that Spark can also hold temporary SQL tables in its catalog, but that these temporary tables are not visible to others who might be logged into the Spark cluster.

So what I'm confused by is, why would you ever really want to create a SQL table that is stored directly in Spark? My understanding is that because it is neither an OLTP database nor a data warehouse, it would not be a good location to try to store permanent database tables. But why would you even want to create temporary tables since you already have your dataframe variables that you can work with?

I understand why it is useful to be able to interact with dataframes using SQL-like operations like `.filter` or `.select`, because it is easy if you understand SQL. But you don't need to create tables in the Spark catalog in order to use those functions. Basically what I'm asking is why would you use `.createOrReplaceTempView()` to move your dataframes into the catalog?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> why would you even want to create temporary tables since you already have your dataframe variables that you can work with?

1. As you guessed and Stephen mentioned: Use in SQL. You can not `select * from "dataframe"`, but you can `select * from "temp view created from a dataframe"`.
2. It makes programming easier.

Imagine writing a complex pyspark program with many classes/modules/functions. If you have a few such "dataframe variables" that you want to use in 4 different functions in 2 different classes, you'll have to pass the variables around as function parameters or member variables etc.

Instead if you `createOrReplaceTempView()`, then anywhere else in the program where you want to use those "dataframe variables", you have access to the temp views by name. AND there is no overhead as it's just an alias. It makes your program much cleaner, readable, compartmentalized.

A very crude comparison would be making a variable class member variable instead of passing it around as function parameter.

---

> but that these temporary tables are not visible to others who might be logged into the Spark cluster.

- Yes. But that's not the only use of these views.
- There is also a `createGlobalTempView()`. This one gives some good info: [spark createOrReplaceTempView vs createGlobalTempView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774187/spark-createorreplacetempview-vs-createglobaltempview)

---

> If the result is a small aggregation you might pull the results back to Python, whereas if it's larger you might push the resulting dataframes to a warehouse as permanent SQL tables.

One thing you must always remember is that [Spark is lazy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/quickstart_df.html).

> *When Spark transforms data, it does not immediately compute the transformation but plans how to compute later. When actions such as collect() are explicitly called, the computation starts.*

It will not do/execute anything until you invoke [an action](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#actions) on it. Of course [writing a dataframe](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-data-sources.html) to a supported sink is also an action. `createOrReplaceTempView()` is NOT an action.

So onus is on YOU to define where the result is "stored". I.e. in memory, or in some persistent sink like S3, ADLS etc. E.g. Spark will simply crash with OOM if you `broadcast()` a 1PB `Dataframe` on machines with insufficient memory.

---

Lastly when you look under the hood, temp views are not "materialized views", they're more like an alias.

```py
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([('Alice', 1)], ['name', 'age'])
>>> df.createOrReplaceTempView('foo9')
>>> df2 = spark.createDataFrame([('math',),('art',)], ['subject',])
>>> df3 = spark.sql('select * from foo9')
>>> df4 = df2.join(df3)
>>> df4.explain(mode='extended')
== Parsed Logical Plan ==
Join Inner
:- LogicalRDD [subject#4], false
+- Project [name#0, age#1L]
   +- SubqueryAlias foo9                           <<---
      +- View (`foo9`, [name#0,age#1L])
         +- LogicalRDD [name#0, age#1L], false

== Analyzed Logical Plan ==
subject: string, name: string, age: bigint
Join Inner
:- LogicalRDD [subject#4], false
+- Project [name#0, age#1L]
   +- SubqueryAlias foo9
      +- View (`foo9`, [name#0,age#1L])
         +- LogicalRDD [name#0, age#1L], false

== Optimized Logical Plan ==
Join Inner
:- LogicalRDD [subject#4], false
+- LogicalRDD [name#0, age#1L], false

== Physical Plan ==
CartesianProduct
:- *(1) Scan ExistingRDD[subject#4]
+- *(2) Scan ExistingRDD[name#0,age#1L]

>>>
```

Comment: Thanks - the point about making it easier to refer to it without passing around a variable makes a ton of sense.

Answer (score 2):

Re temp views...

Although you mention pyspark, for which this answer isn't 100% as obvious, sql is a simple text language that most business analysts and business people understand, it has tonnes of information available on the internet to learn with and works with many different databases.  It's also pretty convenient for certain types of query.

How do you make a correlated subquery in the Spark DSL's ?  You don't, you re-write it as a join.  In 3.4 you can write it as SQL (with some limitations such as aliases and requiring first or similar).

So that said:

> why would you ever really want to create a SQL table that is stored directly in Spark?

it's not "stored" in Spark, the SQL in sparkSession.sql is converted to DataFrame/Set just like your direct use of filter/select. The location of the data could be in another database.

Temp views are a simple convenience, becoming available as a table in sparkSession, they just represent a cached query plan (not ".cache"d data).

In the case of Scala or Java allowing configuration of transformation execution via SQL views can allow complex DSL equivalent code to be handled by simpler SQL that most developers and business people alike should understand.  No need to manage jars or on the fly compilation (although that's clearly what Spark is doing).

[Quality](https://sparkutils.github.io/quality/latest/advanced/viewLoader/) explicitly provides this as managing joins / lookups etc. for DQ/transformation rules is more "end-user" friendly with quicker turnaround than having all small changes going through developers.  In this scenario adding a new join or view that can be used in rules is just a row in a database.

The downside of this approach is the compiler / IDE can't help much as the code is actually managed elsewhere and potentially not even available until runtime.

So you get the extra flexibility of being able to quickly change queries in a language designed for doing just that as well as all the other benefits Spark's MPP engine provides. In addition whether or not .sql is used is completely transparent to any other code that works with DataFrames so it also allows transformation or selection prototyping.

Re "catalog"...

Things get a little less clear when talking about STS (Spark Thrift Server), the thing that looks like Hive.  This acts like a non acid / two phase commit database.  You can still store files externally and just use them as normal file based dataframes, or sql via the catalog, or you can access them via SQL over Thrift.  Choosing to have the data fully managed by Spark may or may not make sense for a given use case.

The use case here is clear, you reporting / BI tool can issue SQL queries and get back results from the same data your other Spark processes use or generate without additional ETL processes into a "proper" database.

Edit: An additional note on catalog wrt. views, when you are using micro-batching (structured streaming with foreachBatch) both the SparkSession.active and it's underlying catalog will be different and temp views are not shared across the "outer" application and the microbatch within the foreachBatch call.

Comment: Thanks for your response. So I think I'm understanding that the tables are not ever really stored in Spark, it's more like an "alias" (view) for a series of commands that would lead to a particular result. But I'm still a little unclear on whether the views can be shared across processes, or whether when I create a view in a script I'm only creating it for myself. Can you clarify? Are you saying that with STS I would be able to share them? Bear in mind I'm a beginner here so some of this is going over my head :)

Comment: Correct, thinking of it as an alias is 100% the way to view it.  Per the [temp view docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#createOrReplaceTempView(viewName:String):Unit) and [global](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html#createOrReplaceTempView(viewName:String):Unit) name temp views only exist for an application.  They do not exist across applications (and therefore processes). 
The hive / STS tables *is* shared across applications and these are better thought of as a non acid database (not 'aliases').

Answer (score 0):

To be able to query your dataframes data using spark.sql, you need to create temp view.

Dataframe has methods

```
dF.createTempView("myData")
dF.createOrReplaceTempView("myData")
```

it assigns `myData` alias to the dataframe and it can be used in the spark.sql

```
dF2=spark.sql ("select * from myData")
```

spark.sql also returns a dataframe, so you can create a temporary view from it and use again in the query.

You can reference many temporary views in the same query as well as hive tables, for example join them, etc.